# Xcode editor canvas live auroresizing and autolayout for UITableViewCell

Tags: xcode, autolayout

So this handy feature that I used so much just don't work with Autolayout ? Or how it is ? I cannot find any info anywhere about this, but for me it seems that it is not working with UITableViewCell because its content view is not resizing. And I have to check if I have correct layout at runtime and before with "springs and struts" a was able to move window in editor and see if it sizes layout correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Best is not to use UITableViewCell in UI designer at all, design there view using autolayout and the add it to content view of cell. This code uses some custom code...

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self dequeueReusableCell:[UITableViewCell className]];
if (!cell) {
    cell = [UITableViewCell.alloc initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:[UITableViewCell className]];
    UIView *view = viewClass.create;
    view.width = [cell width];
    view.height = [cell height];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:view];
}
```